# Vectorisation of nearest neighbour

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of my simple nearest neighbour function but I'm not very well versed when it comes to vectorisation with numpy. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def knn_search(pts_a, pts_b, k):
    """
    Finds the k nearest neighbours of each point in pts_a in pts_b
    :param pts_a:
    :param pts_b:
    :param k:
    :return dist, idx:
    """

    dist = np.empty((pts_b.shape[0], pts_a.shape[0]))
    for i in range(pts_b.shape[0]):
        dist[i, :] = np.linalg.norm(pts_a - pts_b[i, :], axis=1)

    idx = np.argsort(dist, axis=1)
    dist = np.sort(dist, axis=1)

    return dist[:, :k], idx[:, :k]


a = np.random.rand(10, 2)
b = np.random.rand(10, 2)

distance, indices = knn_search(a, b, 5)
```

Comment: Have a look at a KDTree aproach. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree

Comment: thanks, I have used it. This was more to understand the vectorisation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your loop with an outer difference using broadcasting:

```
def knn_search(pts_a, pts_b, k):
    """
    Finds the k nearest neighbours of each point in pts_a in pts_b
    :param pts_a:
    :param pts_b:
    :param k:
    :return dist, idx:
    """

    dist = np.linalg.norm(pts_a - pts_b[:, None], axis=-1)
    idx = np.argsort(dist, axis=1)
    dist = np.sort(dist, axis=1)

    return dist[:, :k], idx[:, :k]
```